ServiceStack and Windows Auth
I am using the latest version of ServiceStack (as of the time I am writing, version 8.5) and I need to integrate Windows Authentication into my application. I know that ServiceStack doesn't provide a specific auth provider for this. I could create a custom WindowsAuthProvider, but I’m not entirely convinced, as security is always a delicate matter. Is there another way?

There is AspNetWindowsAuthProvider in the source code, possibly relevant? https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AspNetWindowsAuthProvider.cs

For .NET Framework you can use ServiceStack Auth with the AspNetWindowsAuthProvider.
For .NET 8+ you would need to Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core.

Thanks, but how can i create a servicestack session if I use Windows auth and asp.net 8?

You'd need to use a Auth Provider that maps the claims principals to User Sessions like the NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider. You can try starting with the mvcauth template and replacing the other Auth Providers with Windows Auth.
